# selector for table inside iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

i have a page with 5 iframe elements. each of them has a document inside it. One of the iframe has a table called hawbtable. I want to find the number of rows in the hawb table,  alert the value for each "hawb" column in each row

in the iframe with id="body" name="body" .. 
i have a table called "hawbTable" which has ten rows ... 
each row has a column called "Hawb" ...
I want to log the value in that cell in the console. How do i do this?

I have been trying to identify the contents of an iframe but they are not returned as elements. Instead they are returned as array due to which selectors will not work on them

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/jquery-ui2.css">
<title>EZ-VIEW Reports</title>
<meta name="chromesniffer" id="chromesniffer_meta"
    content="{&quot;jQuery&quot;:&quot;1.9.1&quot;,&quot;jQuery UI&quot;:&quot;1.10.3&quot;}">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="chrome-extension://homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae/detector.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #fff; margin-left: 0; margin-top: 0;">
    <div id="StayFocusd-infobar" style="display: none;">
        <img
            src="chrome-extension://laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji/common/img/eye_19x19_red.png">
        <span id="StayFocusd-infobar-msg"></span> <span
            id="StayFocusd-infobar-links"> <a
            id="StayFocusd-infobar-never-show">hide forever</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a id="StayFocusd-infobar-hide">hide once</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <table width="1200" border="0" align="left">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="left"><iframe src="Header.jsp?stflg=C"
                        name="head" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="head"
                        style="height: 160px; width: 100%;"></iframe></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="searchCell" width="21%" align="left" style="width: 2%;"><iframe
                        style="height: 590px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 0px; width: 100%;"
                        frameborder="0" id="search" name="search" src="DDSReportSearch.do"
                        scrolling="no"></iframe></td>
                <td id="bodyCell" width="79%" style="width: 95%;"><iframe
                        style="overflow-x: hidden; height: 590px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;"
                        frameborder="0" id="body" name="body" scrolling="auto"
                        src="body.jsp"></iframe></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="left"><iframe src="Footer.jsp"
                        name="head" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="head2"
                        style="height: 30px; width: 1200px; text-align: right;"></iframe></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
        style="border: 0px; display: none; background-color: transparent;"></iframe>
    <div id="GOOGLE_INPUT_CHEXT_FLAG" input="null"
        input_stat="{&quot;tlang&quot;:true,&quot;tsbc&quot;:true,&quot;pun&quot;:true,&quot;mk&quot;:false,&quot;ss&quot;:true}"
        style="display: none;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dont  you got any better name and id other than body ? And where is the hawb table and body iframe in the code!!

Comment: i answered my question below.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#body').contents().find('#hawbTable>tbody>tr').each(function(){
    var tr=this;
    console.log(tr);

    });
```